# PHP function block like in Verilog HDL

Tags: php, function, verilog, block, diagram

I do love programming, but I do love do function in a diagram block as in the image. Does any IDE support function block for PHP?I commonly use PHP to do website project.

Anyone got ideas or experience? I appreciate those who help me. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: PHP is (obviously!) not a hardware description language. It isn't really suited to that kind of layout.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @duskwuff.

Answer (score 0):

I have a gem called [rubyit](https://rubygems.org/gems/ruby_it), which is command line utility to parse files with erb (ruby) and generate the standard version of the file. Which can be used for extendable verilog templates.

Using perl for this is also common, you just need a to expand the perl parts to print out standard verilog. If you viewed verilog as just a text file you could pass it through a php parser to generate standard a verilog file.

Unfortunately I do not know of any IDE which can handle this type of syntax.